# How to write a function of type a-> b -> b -> b for folding a tree

Tags: haskell, tree, append, fold

Some background: I have a foldT function (like foldr but for trees) of the following type in Haskell.

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
```

This foldT only takes type (a -> b -> b -> b) as an input function.

I am trying to find a way to convert my tree into a list, and cannot figure out a way to make my append function take the form (a -> b -> b -> b).

The following is ineffective because it is not the correct type:

```
append x y z = append x:y:z
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: While the type of `foldT` makes it possible to make a good guess, you should add the definition of your tree data type.

Comment: You probably want something like `toList = foldT (\c l r -> l ++ [c] ++ r) []`, although you haven't told us if you want the conversion to list to be in-order, pre-order, or post-order.

Comment: What does the first argument *do* with its arguments? It seems like it is almost certainly duplicating some of what `foldT` itself already does: recursively doing to the subtrees what it does to the root and combining the three.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you haven't posted it, I will assume your tree is...

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

... and that the `a -> b -> b -> b` argument to `foldT` takes the fields of the `Node` constructor in the same order they were declared.

> I am trying to find a way to convert my tree into a list

Let's begin tackling this by following the types:

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
```

You want to flatten it into a list, so the result type of your function must be `[a]`:

```
treeToList :: Tree a -> [a]
```

That give us a good idea on how to continue:

```
treeToList t = foldT f z t
```

With:

```
f :: a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
z :: [a]
t :: Tree a
```

Now, onward to the arguments. `z` is what will be inserted in lieu of the valueless `Leaf`s, and so it must be `[]`. As for `f`, it must combine the sublists created from the left and right branches with the value directly in the `Node`. Assuming an in-order traversal, we have:

```
 treeToList t = foldT (\x l r -> l ++ x : r) [] t
```

Or, without mentioning `t`:

```
 treeToList = foldT (\x l r -> l ++ x : r) []
```

And that's it. One caveat is that repeatedly using left-nested `(++)` (which will happen in this case, as `foldT` walks down the branches recursively) can get quite inefficient. In a situation in which you would care about performance it would be worth considering alternative ways of implementing the concatenating function, such as [difference lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-DList.html).

P.S.: A note about terminology. Saying that a function is "like foldr but for trees" is ambiguous, as there are two well-known kinds of functions analogous to `foldr`. First, you have the methods of the `Foldable` class (cf. [Benjamin Hodgson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39977162/2751851)), which flatten the tree into a list as they fold it, no matter what you do. Then there are the more powerful *catamorphisms*, such as the `foldT` you are using, which are able to make use of the tree structure.

Answer (score 4):

Yuck, why are you writing *code*? GHC can automatically fill in an instance of [the `Foldable` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable), which contains the [`toList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:toList) you're looking for.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
import Data.Foldable

data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Foldable

treeToList :: Tree a -> [a]
treeToList = toList
```

This definition of `treeToList` will perform a [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order) because of the order of the fields of the `Node` constructor.

Comment: Thank you, but my assignment requires me to write my own foldr for trees.

Comment: I get an error with this code: `error: Variable not in scope: toList :: Tree a -> [a]`. I'm using GCH 8.4.4.

Comment: @user2023370 thanks, fixed the code. I forgot to import the module

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the tree onto a list then the function is relatively easy,
so basically if you have tree structure such as:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Then you'd have to extract the value from the tree and add the first value onto an empty list, then apply the same method to the other branches of the tree  recursively with the help of the list (++) operator to append all results onto a single list, i.e.:

```
toList :: Tree a -> [a]
toList Leaf                    =    []
toList (Node left value right) =    [value] ++ toList left ++ toList right
```

then to fold it, first:

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
```

The function signature is missing an argument here lets look at the signature: **a(first argument) -> b (second) -> b (third) -> b (return type)**  the function takes **3 arguments**/parameters but **the signature** you provided **only has 1 b type** (which im guessing is your accumulator), so basically this would be the function signature you're looking for:

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
```

Now we can work with this signature, then let's move onto the function:

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldT f acc Leaf                    =   acc
foldT f acc (Node left value right) =   foldT f (foldT f (f value acc) left) right
```

Although I don't think I should be giving you the answer and you should practice a bit more with recursive data structures so you can better understand how to traverse through them.

Comment: I didn't but I would guess you were downvoted for either providing the wrong answer. Or that you "don't think I should be giving you the answer" as this is a Q&A site, so providing the answer if kind of the point of it...

Comment: @Jack I know this is old and is been a while but the answer was correct and I did provide the answer. I was just downvoted by a funny guy who probably didn't like me writing "I don't think I should be giving you the answer", but I had my reasons for saying that.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you start with every time is just to start matching patterns :)  At that point, it's pretty much mechanical!

Assuming you have:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

Let's start matching patterns! :)

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldT f z ...
```

What's the first `Tree` constructor?  It's `Leaf`!

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldT f z Leaf = ...
```

What could we put there?  We need something of type `b`...and we only have one one way to get it.  by using `z` :)

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldT f z Leaf = z
```

And so, mechanically, we can move on to the next possible pattern:

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldT f z Leaf           = z
foldT f z (Node t1 x t2) =
```

Well, we can just make it `z`, but that's a little boring.  We probably want to use `t1`, `x`, and `t2`.  We can use `f`, which needs something of type `a`...and we have `x :: a` :)

```
foldT :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldT f z Leaf           = z
foldT f z (Node t1 x t2) = f x ??? ???
```

`f` has two more arguments, of type `b`, so what do you think we could put there?  We can put `z` twice, but that's a little boring.  How can we get `b`'s from `t1` and `t2`?